# Functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

This looks really simple.  I want to define a function:

`syms x`

`f = x^2`

I want to be able to do `f(4)` and it spits out 16.  I also want to avoid having to write a new m-file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with symbolic variables, to substitute in a numeric value, use [`subs()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/subs.html), i.e. symbolic substitution:

```
syms x
f = x^2

subs(f,4)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>> f = @(x) x^2;
>> f(4)

ans =

    16
```

Comment: Note that the `x` in the function handle is NOT the symbolic `x` you defined.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: You are creating a function on-the-fly which accepts one input, whose name is specified within the `( )`. The name itself can be anything and it will not match base workspace variables since each function has it's own workspace when called.